# How to create URL for every MongoDB document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to map a URL using express routes to a specific value from every document I have in the database.

For example. In the Schema company.name would return a company name.

Is there a way to set the value of company.name to a unique URL?

The only way I thought of it was creating a loop or using mongoose's .find to iterate through the database and set it to

```
app.get('/' + name , function (req , res ) {
   res.render('company.jade');
});
```

However I'm not sure how to access the database collections from the routes file.

Using

```
const Company = require('.models/company');
```

Doesn't return the database so not sure what to do.

I'm not really hip on Mongoose or node.js yet. Really only need to do this one thing and the rest of the app is done in angular which I'm more familiar with.

Hopefully I made some sense here. I do have code for the app buts it's all basic code from app.js and routes.js. I can add it if it would be helpful.

Comment: Can you show me your MongoDB document for example, and be clear with what you want to be done?

Comment: Yeah I'll have to shorten it for the comment but essentially { company { 'name' : Microsoft} }, { company { 'name' : Apple } } and I want to generate url's /Microsoft /Apple etc. for each one. Sorry if that's not clear

Comment: This kinda thing should generally be done with a GET or POST request. Not knowing the way your server is set up makes this a bit hard to answer, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for Mongoose `findOne` [query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html).

```
const Company = require('.models/company');

app.get('/:name', function(req, res){
Company.findOne({'company.name': req.params.name}) //company.name depends upon the schema you set.
 .then(function(company){
   if (company)
    return res.send({success: true, data: company}); //return company as an object containing the queried company document.

   else 
    return res.send({success: false, error: 'Company not found'});

 })
 .catch(function(err){
  if (err) res.send({success: false, error: err}); 
 });
});
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for, thanks. I was trying a bunch of things and it looks like I wasn't using the correct query, thanks